# Isolating values of a vector based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have created a function:

```r
rcos2 <- function(x) {
  ((cos(x))^2)/3.142813
}
```

and a resulting sample:

```r
sample <- rcos2(runif(1000,0,2*pi))
```

I want to use the condition:

```r
maxdens <- max(sample)
```

To find values that satisfy this condition:

```r
accepted <- ifelse(runif(1000,0,2*pi) < (sample/maxdens), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Basically what I'm asking is how can I plot only the values in 'accepted' that would be computed as being TRUE?

Comment: `ifelse(foo, TRUE, FALSE)` is a [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm). You’d want to say simply `foo`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: In fear of being a complete pedant, I think 'tautology' is the more commonly used term in cases like this (discrete mathematics/formal logic).

Comment: @AkselA In formal logic, `TRUE` itself is a tautology, the word is thus misleading in this context. So, to be pedantic, both “tautology” (in the context of grammar) and “pleonasm” are correct but the latter is clearer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "`TRUE` itself is a tautology". Please explain.

Comment: @AkselA It’s easy to explain: it’s wrong.  Apologies. I’ll go back to using “tautology” from now on.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I can see how 'pleonasm' would be the right word, as `ifelse(foo, TRUE, FALSE)` is unnecessarily verbose, in a stylistic/language kind of way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
set.seed(1)
r <- runif(1000,0,2*pi)

sample <- rcos2(r)

maxdens <- max(sample)

plot(r[r < sample/max(sample)])
```

Or without storing the intermediate values

```
set.seed(1)
r <- runif(1000,0,2*pi)

plot(r[r < rcos2(r)/max(rcos2(r))])
```

[image]

The use of square brackets is standard subsetting syntax in R.
`r < rcos2(r)/max(rcos2(r))` creates a logical vector of the same length as `r`, and by putting it inside the square brackets like this, only the elements of `r` whose index is `TRUE` are selected and plotted.